# Site-wide method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've created a floating, ever-present Feedback button for my site that launches a popup form using magnific-popup.

It's visible everywhere but I don't know where to put the build method for it so that it will create the Feedback object.

I can put this in to a controller to make it work:

```
@feedback = current_user.feedbacks.build
```

but surely I don't have to add that to every controller?

Can I put it in applications_controller? If so what should I call the method?

In my feedbacks_controller I have

```
def create
        @feedback = current_user.feedbacks.build(feedback_params)
        if @feedback.save
            flash[:success] = "Feedback fed back!"
            redirect_to :back
        end
end

    private

        def feedback_params
            params.require(:feedback).permit(:user_id, :nature, :content, :url, :status)
        end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `before_action :set_feedback` in your `application_controller.rb`

```
def set_feedback
    @feedback = current_user.feedbacks.build
end
```

This should do the trick. It will be called in all the controller.

Just to be up to date with the current version of rails, `before_filter` is now called `before_action`.

Also, as pointed out in the comments, you can skip the filter using the `skip_before_action` in a controller where you don't need to set the `@feedback`

All the controller callbacks are described in the APIDock: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/skip_before_action

Comment: Just make sure that you skip the before filter on any actions that don't require it